# Storing persistent settings for each product in list

Tags: c#, design, storage, settings

Sorry if I'm not clear, I didn't touch the program for almost two weeks.

I have a program that reads XML files:

- A product list
- Each product's default settings (if custom is not available)
- Each product's custom settings

Then it constructs a `ProductBase` object and `ProductSettings` from either default or custom XML. Afterwards they form a `Product` object, which is put into a list, and then a WPF DataGrid is filled with list elements.

I'm using very questionable ways to do all this (I'm a beginner) - I realized I should start over because the code is nigh unreadable, and I'm asking here in case I should take a different route while I'm at it. I'm pretty sure current way will make me suffer later on, as even now it causes me headaches.

I need a way to store products list with a possibility to save each product settings (like "is in delivery", or "do not sell" bools) between sessions. It also should take in consideration that product count might change, but it should keep old settings for products that weren't added/removed.

Is there a standard way to do this? It surely must have been done many times. I'm open for any suggestion.

Edit: The product lists aren't huge (probably no more than 100KB), product settings consist of two booleans per product. It would be helpful if it could be portable, but there is no real need for it. I was thinking about a light database, but I couldn't find anything easy to use. Except Sqlite, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: As it stands, this question is far too  broad to be answered. We don't know what constraints or other requirements you have to meet.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I'm not sure what else I should provide. The product lists aren't huge (probably no more than 100KB), product settings consist of two booleans per product. It would be helpful if it could be portable, but there is no real need for it. I was thinking about a light database, but I couldn't find anything easy to use. Except Sqlite, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: do you mean "each product *types* default setting"? Or do the default and custom settings contain different properties? I'm confused since I do not see any need to store both default and custom settings for each product if only one will be used.

Comment: @user104903 All products are considered equal. I want it to act like this, both setting bools should default to `false`, thus every new product would start with `false` bools. Otherwise it should use user settings. Sorry, I'm pretty new to programming, and it's basically the first project I had to actually design (I wish I did it before I started...)

Comment: @xtl: I think you misunderstood user104903. When you say "each product's default settings", that implies that each **individual** product has **individual** default settings. If that is the case, then these individual settings already are the "custom" settings as they are unique to the product. Hence the need for clarification.

Comment: @Flater Ah, that makes perfect sense, I'm sorry. After a while I realized my case fits very well to a light database. Of course I'm still open for other solutions, probably for education's sake, because I liked SQLite so much I'd find it hard to move away from it.
To be clear: every product is assigned multiple columns of `true`/`false` settings. Each product can have a different setup of `true`s and `false`s, but they always default to `false` in all fields. It was very hard to explain because I attempted to apply it to an XML setup, while DB was an obvious solution I somehow managed to miss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went with SQLite solution. One table contains dynamic product list, second table contains settings linked to each product. Simple trigger does all the work to link these tables. It's simpler than XML on literally every front. I wish I decided to go this way right at the beginning.